# Duda al borrar un registro de la base de datos desde PHP

Tags: php, sql

Estoy intentando hacer una tabla que borre registros de la base de datos.

Tengo esta tabla:
Clientes (Dni,apellnom,password,telefono) donde:
- Dni contiene el dni de cada uno de los clientes
- apellnom, contiene el nombre y apellidos de los clientes
- telefono: contiene el teléfono del cliente

y este es el index que muestro:
[image: tabla]
He conseguido que me borre los clientes que solo tienen el DNI numérico, pero los que tienen letra no los borra. Se que sera un fallo tonto en la select, o unas comillas pero por mas que pruebo no doy con ello.
Os dejo el código por si me podéis ayudar.

pagina principal:

````
session_start();
include("funcionBorrado.php");
include('funciones.php');
if(isset($_SESSION["tipo"])){
    cabecera('Conectado como ' . $_SESSION["tipo"]. ' ('. $_SESSION["nombre"]. ')'.' -- INMOBILARIA');
}
else{
    cabecera('No conectado');
}echo "<div id=\"contenido\">\n";
echo "<h1>Dar de baja a Clientes</h1>";
echo "</div>";

if(isset($_SESSION) && $_SESSION["usuario"]=="1111A"){

    $conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","inmobiliaria");
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");
?>
<table border="1" bgcolor="#d9dadb" width="500px" align=center>
    <tr>
        <th width="41%">DNI</th>
        <th width="50%">Nombre y apellidos</th>
        <th width="9%">Borrar</th>
    </tr>
<?php 
    $sql = "select * from clientes";
    $result = db_query($sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row->Dni;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->apellnom;?></td>
        <td>
   <a class="btn btn-primary" href="borrarCliente.php?Dni=<?php echo $row->Dni;?>"><i color="black" class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } }else{
    // si no es el admnistrador, nos sale el siguiente mensaje:
    echo"<p align=center>Debe ser el administrador para ver esta página</p>";

}
?>```


Funcion borrado:

<?php
function db_query($query) {
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","inmobiliaria");
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

    return $result;
}

function delete($tblname,$field_Dni,$Dni){ //Funcion para borrar registros

    $sql = "delete from ".$tblname." where ".$field_Dni."=".$Dni."";

    return db_query($sql);
}

function select_Dni($tblname,$field_name,$field_Dni){
    $sql = "Select * from ".$tblname." where ".$field_name." = ".$field_Dni."";
    $db=db_query($sql);
    $GLOBALS['row'] = mysqli_fetch_object($db);

    return $sql;
}
?>

Funcion borrarCliente:

<?php 
include("funcionBorrado.php");
$Dni = $_GET['Dni'];
delete('clientes','Dni',$Dni);
header("location:borrar_clientes.php");
?>
````

Comment: Te faltan unas comillas simples en `WHERE dni='".$Dni."'`

Comment: Y, definitivamente, ahora que estás aprendiendo, de verdad, vete poco a poco... debes aprender a hacer ejemplos sencillos con los que probar las cosas. Te va a resultar muy difícil depurar tanto código como el que nos envías

Comment: Usa consultas preparadas te harán incluso más fácil la lectura de tu código

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, se que hay formas mas eficientes de hacerlo, pero es la forma que me están enseñando :( . Tendré que mirarme por mi cuenta las consultas preparadas que ya varios me lo habéis recomendado. La verdad que la forma que me están enseñando el php es un poco raro, y mas ahora, que no tengo clases y lo único que hacen es mandarme grandes aplicaciones en las que tengo que buscarme la vida con los pocos ejemplos que nos dio.

Comment: Cuando trabajes en esto, seguro que te encontrarás cosas peores... pero siempre dependerá de ti simplificarlas. ¿Cómo? Montando un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Sé que cuesta, pero es lo que te permitirá encontrar soluciones a lo que te vaya surgiendo. Si conoces bien las piezas, harás que el conjunto funcione. Te voy a responder a tu pregunta con un ejemplo mínimo, para que veas lo fácil que resulta encontrar el fallo que tenías a partir de algo simplificado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos a montar un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verficable de fallo que comentas.

Empezamos por el dataset, que consistirá en una tabla y unos registros de ejemplo que ilustren los casos que comentas:

```
CREATE TABLE clientes(
  dni varchar(15),
  apellnom varchar(31),
  passwd varchar(255),
  telefono varchar(15)
  );
INSERT INTO clientes (dni, apellnom) VALUES
  ('333','lola'),
  ('6789L','Lopez, Juan'),
  ('789L','ruiz, pepe');
```

Y ahora vamos con las consultas. No hace falta que empecemos borrando, con un simple `SELECT` servirá para ver si se localizan los registros que quieres borrar:

```
SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE dni=333;

SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE dni=789L;

SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE dni='789L';
```

La primera consulta funciona correctamente, la segunda da error y, la tercera, también funciona.

Conclusión: faltaban las comillas simples en el `WHERE`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me es muy útil.